# iframe not loading properly

Tags: php, html, iframe

I am loading a page in an iframe. This is the code i am using:

File: **iframe_load.html**

```
<?php echo 'URL = '.$_REQUEST['url']; ?>
<iframe width="1015px" id="article_frame" src="<?php echo $_REQUEST['url']; ?>" style="border:0 none;"  height="576px" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

In my browser if i am browse this url:

> http://mywebsite.com/iframe_load.html?url=http://www.northjersey.com/r?19=961&43=515347&44=234450391&32=4497&7=309037&40=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.northjersey.com%2Fnews%2FSecret_bunker_under_Prague_hotel_opens_to_public_.html&nid=4306612

then the $_REQUEST['url'] only showing the value partially. So my iframe not showing the actual page content. Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me simplify that URL for demonstration purposes:

`http://yoursite.com/iframe_load.html?url=http://theirsite.com/index.php?a=1&b=2`

Notice that their website's URL contains a query string (`index.php?a=1&b=2`) as well. Because the URL contains `&`, this is how PHP splits the string:

1. `url=http://theirsite.com/index.php?a=1` &
2. `b=2`

As you see, `url` now only holds a part of the URL, not the complete URL (because it was split by `&`).

The `&` sign 'breaks' the URL too soon, so you have to replace it with something that doesn't break the URL.

**You must pass iframe_load.html an encoded URL, to prevent PHP from mis-interpreting the URL:**

`http://yoursite.com/iframe_load.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftheirsite.com%2Findex.php%3Fkey1%3Dval1%26key2%3Dval2`

(see that the part after `iframe_load.html?url=` doesn't contain any `?` or `&` anymore)

If you link to **iframe_load.html** from another page, you can use PHP's function [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/urlencode) to do this for you:

**some page that links to iframe_load.html**

```
<?php
// create a variable with the URL
// this is the normal URL, we will encode it later, when we echo it.
$other_websites_url = 'http://theirsite.com/index.php?key1=val1&key2=val2';
?>

<a href="http://yoursite.com/iframe_load.html?url=<?php echo urlencode($other_websites_url); ?>">Click to go to iframe_load.html</a>
<?php //                                                     ^ see, here we urlencode the URL, just before we paste it inside our own URL.
```

Using `urlencode()`, the special characters in the URL (such as `&`) are changed into HTML entities, so they (temporarily) loose their meaning, and don't break the URL. Don't worry, the URL will be decoded when you access it in iframe_load.html, so you'll have the correct URL for the iframe.

This is what their website's URL looks like when it's encoded: `http%3A%2F%2Ftheirsite.com%2Findex.php%3Fkey1%3Dval1%26key2%3Dval2`

As you can see, `&` has been replaced with `%26`, and other characters have been replaced as well. Now you can simply paste it into your URL:

`http://yoursite.com/iframe_load.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftheirsite.com%2Findex.php%3Fkey1%3Dval1%26key2%3Dval2`

Because the URL of the other website doens't contain `&` anymore, PHP won't split the URL.

Comment: After using the **urlencode()** function i am getting the url like this:

  URL = http%3A%2F%2Fwww.northjersey.com%2Fr%3F19%3D961 only.

Comment: You need to use it when you **link to** iframe_load.html, not within iframe_load.html itself.

Comment: In other words, when you visit **iframe_load.html**, the URL after `iframe_load.html?url=` should already be encoded. This way, iframe_load.html doesn't split the URL in parts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the url parameter. Try this URL :

http://mywebsite.com/iframe_load.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.northjersey.com%2Fr%3F19%3D961%2643%3D515347%2644%3D234450391%2632%3D4497%267%3D309037%2640%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.northjersey.com%252Fnews%252FSecret_bunker_under_Prague_hotel_opens_to_public_.html%26nid%3D4306612

Answer (score 0):

Please do it as following:

```
$datum = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);   /*use this if you want to get current page path*/
$test = "http://mywebsite.com/iframe_load.html?url=http://www.northjersey.com/r?19=961&43=515347&44=234450391&32=4497&7=309037&40=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.northjersey.com%2Fnews%2FSecret_bunker_under_Prague_hotel_opens_to_public_.html&nid=4306612";
$datum = parse_url($test);
print_R($datum['query']);
```

Comment: it only printing **19=961**

Comment: @ARUN I tried with the string `$test`. Please check again without url_encode()

Comment: @ARUN Please copy my code and execute it. And do tweak as per your need.

Comment: if i copy your code as it is, then it is working. But if i replace the $test value like this `$test = $_REQUEST['url'];` then it is not working.

Comment: @ARUN Please dont use `$_REQUEST['url']`. Use my first line as I shown in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

url encode the part after of the url variable not the whole URL, you need to change at the point from where the URL is actually originating not where it is parsed:

```
$url_param_val = urlencode("http://www.northjersey.com/r?19=961&43=515347&44=234450391&32=4497&7=309037&40=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.northjersey.com%2Fnews%2FSecret_bunker_under_Prague_hotel_opens_to_public_.html&nid=4306612");

$new_url = "http://mywebsite.com/iframe_load.html?url=".$url_param_val;
```